# Return Default message if there is no record to return - sqlplus oracle

Tags: oracle, shell, oracle11g, sqlplus

I am running a view in sqlplus and generating a report then sending an email (mailx). 
if there is no record it's creating an empty excel outfile. 
I would like to validate the sql error code and  if there is no records I would like to include "There is no records for the specified period" in the body of the email message.
Could you suggest how to capture the sql code, so I can change the body of the email with no attachment?
Thanks in advance.

code:

```
sqlplus /@conn<<EOF

WHENEVER SQLERROR EXIT 1 ROLLBACK
WHENEVER OSERROR EXIT 1 ROLLBACK

SET MARKUP HTML ON
SET PAGESIZE 50000
SET FEEDBACK OFF

@/home/user/script.sql;

echo body | mailx
```

script.sql:

```
col spoolname new_value spoolname;
Spool /home/path/file
Select * from schema.file;
```

Thanks for the suggestion.
I have modified the code and below is the error I am getting now.
Error: "Syntax error; unexpected end of file"

Could any of you check and suggest please?

```
sqlplus /@conn<<EOF
<SQL error handling & set values >

@/home/user/script.sql;
EOF                                                                                          
CDATE=$CDATE"`date +"%y%m%d"`.xls";                                                       
ODFILENAME="/home/usr/reports/ ";                                                                 
ODFILENAME=$ODFILENAME"$CDATE";                                                       

if [ -s "$ODFILENAME" ]; then                                                               
    BODY=$BODY"Please find the extract."
else
    BODY=$BODY"Zero KB file."                                                                      
fi                                                                                                                           

mailx
```

Comment: Where's your second EOF? Your shell script code is incomplete.

Comment: `WHENEVER SQLERROR EXIT 1 ROLLBACK` will not exit the session with an exit code for cases where there are no records from a select statement. If you are running a PL/SQL block you may make use of an exception like `no_data_found`. Otherwise, the answer by @kfinity , i.e to check file size in shell should work for you.

Answer (score 0):

I'd do it something like this:

shell script

```
sqlplus -silent /@conn<<EOF

WHENEVER SQLERROR EXIT 1 ROLLBACK
WHENEVER OSERROR EXIT 1 ROLLBACK

SET MARKUP HTML ON
SET PAGESIZE 50000
SET FEEDBACK OFF

@/home/user/script.sql;
EOF

if [ -s /home/path/file ] ; then
  # file is not zero size
  echo body | mailx ...
else
  mailx -s "subject" user@domain.com <<EOF
There is no records for the specified period
.
EOF
fi
```

Comment: Thank for the suggestion, induced this and getting "Syntax error; unexpected end of file error. Anything wrong with the syntax.                               if [ -s "$ODFILENAME" ]; then                                                               
 BODY=$BODY"Please find the extract."
else
 BODY=$BODY"Zero KB file."                                                                      
fi

Answer (score 0):

One option would be to raise `NO_DATA_FOUND` from a PL/SQL block before running your query to fetch a single record to see if  the query gives you output. This will cause the SQL* Plus session to terminate with `SQLERROR`

**Note:** If there are multiple sql queries within the  `script.sql` or if it is a long running query, this may not be very efficient.

something like this is what you could write within sqlplus.

```
WHENEVER SQLERROR EXIT 1 ROLLBACK
WHENEVER OSERROR EXIT 1 ROLLBACK

DECLARE 
v INT;

BEGIN
    SELECT 1
    INTO v
    FROM v_EMPLOYEES  --Your view query for 1 row
    WHERE ROWNUM = 1;  
END;
/

SET MARKUP HTML ON
SET PAGESIZE 50000
SET FEEDBACK OFF
@/home/user/script.sql
```

If it terminates with error this way, the exit code will be captured by the shell environment variable `$?`, which could be made use of in a similar block as that of kfinity's answer.

```
if [ $? -eq 0 ] ;then 
..
..
else
```